# Make CheckBox's background transparent when XPStyle is on

Tags: installation, nsis

**Is it possible to make a Checkboxes background transparent when XPStyle is on?**

The following simple code can make the Checkbox background transparent but ONLY if XPStyle is set to off.

Is there a way to get the checkbox's background transparent while keeping XPStyle on? I really hope so, otherwise I have big problems. I'm open to really out there ideas, no matter how involved they are.

*If theres no way, is it possible to alter the opacity of the checkbox background - maybe I can make it slightly transparent(50%)?*

```
!include "LogicLib.nsh"
!include "MUI2.nsh"
!include WinMessages.nsh

OutFile "abc.exe"
Page Custom CustomPageInitialise

XPStyle on

Function CustomPageInitialise
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $0
    SetCtlColors $0 0xFF0000 0x00FF00

    ${NSD_CreateCheckbox} 25u 20u 100% 20u "Version 8"
    Pop $1
    SetCtlColors $1 0xFF0000 transparent                        # Set tranparent color for control 
    ${NSD_AddExStyle} $1 ${WS_EX_TRANSPARENT}|${WS_EX_TOPMOST}  # Add special style 

    nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Section dummy
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already linked to a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=1420352&group_id=22049&atid=373085) about this in one of your other questions. This is probably a limitation/bug in the theme engine and/or the visual style and to work around it you probably have to create a plugin that subclasses the checkbox and performs painting to a bitmap with WM_PRINT or something like that...

Comment: thanks for all the info u've given me :). Do you know of a example that shows how to subclass a win32 control in NSIS? I've done alot of native WinAPI subclassing of listboxes etc. in C/C++ so this is familiar to me.

Comment: You cannot subclass in NSIS without a plugin. There is a generic subclass plugin but it is hard to use and dealing with bitmaps on top of that is even more work. I'd recommend you write a new plugin for this specific task...